# phone link not working in the android APP

Tags: android

hello i have this link in my website `<a href='tel: 123456789'>1234</a>` and i am converting the website into android APP everything works fine but **this tel link gives me `webpage not available` how can i make this to call the phone instead of treating this as a link in android app.**

i have already added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

i dont know how to fix this link issue should i use any javascript or something ??

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Is it the space?  Is it possible that Android is seeing "123456789" as an invalid phone number and assuming it's a URL?

Comment: i dont know when i open it in browser in phone it works good, but when i open this in the mobile APP it sends me to a link and says webpage not availabe

Comment: From this reference https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/ your phone number should be formatted with a `-` in between numbers

Answer (score 1):

With what I understand, you want to call the number when someone clicks it, you can use this code:

```
String uri = "tel:" + "NUMBER-GOES-HERE" ;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to add permission before the `<application />` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```